# Using modem as home network traffic input and raspberry pi 5 as output

Tags: networking, router, vpn

So my family and I love using a VPN for all sorts of things, and we want all of our traffic to be routed through one (surfshark).

Because we don't live in a city, our home internet system has been at work since the 90s and a certain family member thinks that if I change the router for a new one that can run a VPN, or mess with it in any physical way, it could be catastrophic... I am not trusted even though.

I was thinking there must be a router setting or something that will redirect all traffic to my raspberry pi (which runs the VPN client and will send the traffic out but to the VPN) connected to the same network. We have the average modern ISP router. It must be possible.

Reason why I don't just want to use the Raspberry Pi as a "modem" or "router" that will directly take traffic from end devices is that the already installed infrastructure which works fine with the modem has a larger physical range than the Pi could provide.

Thanks for the help!